# TCP/IP between SIMULINK and PYTHON

Tags: python, simulink, tcp

I am trying to establish a TCP/IP connection between SIMULINK (client) and PYTHON (server). I tried sending the value of a variable in a loop. But the value I receive in SIMULINK is some random values(like 2.5e-09 or something) which hasno relation with the value I sent. I have tried changing the data type on the SIMULINK side.But no luck.

Following is the code in PYTHON:

```
import socket
serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

serversocket.bind(('localhost',30001))
serversocket.listen(5)
(clientsocket, address) = serversocket.accept()

for i in range(0,50):
    msg1='%0.1f\n' %(float(1.1+i))
    clientsocket.send(msg1.encode('utf-8'))

clientsocket.close()
```

Following is my simulink block and the block parameter settings:

[image]

Can somebody please help?

Comment: Maybe try using the [struct module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/struct.html) to encode your data?  Or does Simulink explicitly require utf-8 strings?

Comment: struct module did the job! Thanks a lot. @snakecharmerb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python server is not sending a big endian double which it seems that the client is expecting. Instead it is sending a sequence of new line terminated strings: `1.1\n`, `2.1\n`, ..., `50.1\n`.

You can use the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module to format a float as a big endian double for transmission over the connection.

```
import struct

for i in range(50):
    msg1 = struct.pack('>d', 1.1+i)
    clientsocket.send(msg1)
```

There is no need to UTF8 encode the data since it is a binary value that should be sent.

[`struct.pack()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.pack) takes a format string and a value to pack. In this case the format string `>d` means a big endian double. The returned value is a bytes object representing the packed data. For example the packed value of the float 20.1 is:

```
>>> struct.pack('>d', 20.1)
b'@4\x19\x99\x99\x99\x99\x9a'
```

As you can see, the size for a double is 8 bytes. You might need to set that as the data size in the client.